# Doctrine: How to combine 3 of the table, with the attitude of many to many

Tags: php, doctrine

There are 3 tables:

```
catalog
product
product2catalog
```

Table `product2catalog` consists of the following fields:

```
catalog_id
product_id
```

How to get goods within the directory? How to rebuild the connection to be able to do so:

```
$CatalogTable = CatalogTable::getInstance();
$Catalog = $CatalogTable->find( $id );
var_dump( $Catalog->product );
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many to many relationships are easy in Doctrine, as outlined [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models/en#join-table-associations:many-to-many).

Set up your relationship like this: (in the catalog table's setUp() function)

```
$this->hasMany('Product as Products',
array('local' => 'catalog_id',
      'foreign' => 'product_id',
      'refClass' => 'product2catalog'
    ));
```

Similarly, in YAML:

```
Catalog:
# ...
  relations:
   # ...
    Products:
      class: Product
      local: catalog_id
      foreign: product_id
      refClass: product2catalog
```

You have to also do the same for the product class - exact same syntax, just invert the local/foreign references.

Answer (score 1):

To query a Many-to-Many relationship, you can do something like this:

```
$q = Doctrine_Query::create()
    ->from('Catalogue c')
    ->leftJoin('c.Product p')
    ->where('c.id = ?', $id);

$c = $q->fetchArray();
```